# vsftpd error Listing Directories

Tags: amazon-ec2, ftp, ec2-ami, vsftpd

I installed vsftpd on amazon ec2 with fedora instance and it is the latest version but I am getting the error: 
In CuteFTP:

```
COMMAND:> PASV 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,10,46,14,20)
COMMAND:> LIST
ERROR:> Can’t connect to remote server. Socket error = #10065.
ERROR:> PASV failed, trying PORT.
```

In Filezilla:

```
Command: PASV Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,10,46,14,20)
Command: LIST Error: Connection timed out
Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing.
```

Trying to Connect thro' Shell and showing me list of directories.

Answer (score 71):

Just had this same exact issue... this typically only affects GUI ftp clients that use a passive mode (which is pretty common).  For instance, when using the standard ftp command line tool, I was able to successfully login and upload files to my ftp server.

The steps to correct are:

1. Add the following settings to your /etc/vsftpd.conf file:

   pasv_enable=YES
   pasv_min_port=64000
   pasv_max_port=64321
   port_enable=YES
2. Also add one of the following config chunks to your /etc/vsftpd.conf file, based on your situation (either way, this needs to resolve to a public accessible IP):

a:

```
pasv_address=<your-static-ip-most-likely-from-elastic-ips>
pasv_addr_resolve=NO
```

**-OR-**

b:

```
pasv_address=<your-publicly-resolvable-host-name>
pasv_addr_resolve=YES
```

3. In your security group configuration for ec2 instances, add the following custom inbound tcp rules:

- Enable ports 20-21 for standard ftp
- Enable your passive ports as defined in the config sections above (I used 64000-64321)

4. Restart your vsftpd service (varies depending on your flavor of linux)

Note: pasv port range should be visible outside from the firewall, NAT

References for more info:

- http://www.adrianworlddesign.com/Knowledge-Base/Web-Hosting/Amazon-Web-Services/Enable-FTP-in-EC2
- http://www.synergycode.com/knowledgebase/blog/item/ftp-server-on-amazon-ec2
- https://www.gosquared.com/blog/fix-ftp-passive-mode-problems-on-amazon-ec2-instances

Comment: i think you mixed up pasv_max_port and pasv_min_port

Comment: I was having this same problem even though I had already configured the passive port range and opened those ports.  On a whim I tried switching pasv_addr_resolve to YES and putting my host name in, rather than the IP, and now passive connections work again.  Strange.

Comment: With this configs I even can not start/restart the daemon - `pgrep vsftpd` return nothing :(

Answer (score 20):

`error: failed to retrieve directory listing` on amazon ec2 can be fixed by simply changing **transfer mode to active**.

this post explains how to get it done easily using filezilla:

https://nabtron.com/error-while-connecting-to-amazon-ec2-via-ftp-solution/

Answer (score 4):

With version vsftpd-3.0.2-1.el5.x86_64.rpm for me helped the following settings:

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=64000
pasv_max_port=64321
port_enable=YES
pasv_address=<your-static-ip-most-likely-from-elastic-ips>
pasv_addr_resolve=NO
```

Thanks to the longda!

Answer (score 3):

This work for me;

Below is configuration in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
xferlog_std_format=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
pam_service_name=ftp
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=13000
pasv_max_port=13100
port_enable=YES
pasv_address=AWS-IP-Address
pasv_addr_resolve=no
```

**SAVE and Restart the service**

```
$ sudo service vsftpd restart
```

Open below ports in security group

- custom TCP 20 from 0.0.0.0/0
- custom TCP 21 from 0.0.0.0/0
- custom TCP 13000 from 0.0.0.0/0
- custom TCP 13100 from 0.0.0.0/0

You may get below error while connecting from FileZilla FTP client;

```
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

To resolve this;

- Open Filezilla, go to Edit -> Settings
- Click on Connection -> FTP: Choose Active
- Click on Connection -> FTP -> Active Mode: Select "Ask your operating
  system for the external IP address"
- Click on Connection -> FTP -> Passive Mode: Choose Fall Back to
  Active Mode Press OK.

Try connecting to your FTP site once again.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this thread:

http://www.gosquared.com/liquidicity/archives/936

Comment: new url: https://www.gosquared.com/blog/fix-ftp-passive-mode-problems-on-amazon-ec2-instances

Answer (score 0):

You want to use passive mode if possible. As I said in the article Bucho linked to, you just have to define a port range for PASV mode and open that range in your EC2 security group

Answer (score 0):

if some configuration like below in vsftpd.conf:

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=64000
pasv_max_port=64321
```

try to open firewall:

```
# yum install -y epel-release
# yum install -y ufw
# sudo ufw allow from any to any proto tcp port 64000:64321

sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp –dport 64000:64321 -j ACCEPT
```